# Energy change of isentropic expansion of ideal gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

I'm trying to get a better grasp on dealing with different processes thermodynamic, and this one is giving me trouble.

The differential of energy is given by
$$dU= \delta Q + \delta W~.$$ I'm interested in the ideal gas for a closed system, so $\delta W = -pdV$. For an isentropic process, there is no heat exchange, so $\delta Q =0$. This gives us the result that
$$dU = -pdV ~.$$
Further, for the reversible process, the external pressure against which the system expands is the same as the pressure of the gas, which for an ideal gas is $$p=\frac{NkT}{V}$$
Substituting this into the differential of the energy, we can integrate both sides to find
$$\Delta U = -Nk\int_{V_0}^{V_f}\frac{T(V)dV}{V}$$
In this case, if I'm not mistaken the temperature is not constant (this is an isentropic, not isothermal process), so how does one calculate the energy change of this compression? Is there a relation between $V$ and $T$ I am forgetting?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about an isentropic *reversible* expansion, i.e., one for which dq_*rev* = 0.  That is an adiabatic reversible expansion.  For that, you want to use the relationship between T1 and T2 for an ideal gas for an adiabatic reversible expansion to determine $\Delta U$: $ {\displaystyle T_{2}=T_{1}\left({\frac {P_{2}}{P_{1}}}\right)^{\frac {\gamma -1}{\gamma }}.}$ where $\gamma = \frac{C_p}{C_v}$, $C_p = C_v+nR$, and $C_v = 3/2 nR$ for a monatomic ideal gas and $5/2 nR$ for a diatomic ideal gas.

Comment: You need to also make use of the equation for an ideal gas $dU=NC_VdT$ so that $dU=NC_VdT=-pdV$